# foreach in foreach condition filterings

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Sorry I don't know how to provide a more appropriate subject

How can I get only the remaining arrays (in this case: banana) in the $regular_items array (which doesn't fall into the first 2 conditions)?
I have tried various if conditions for days still doesn't work.

The following codes give me all 3 $cart array in the $regular_items array.

```
<?php
$offers[0]['buy_type'] = 'brand';
$offers[0]['buy_type_id'] = '1';
$offers[0]['name'] = 'brand1';

$offers[1]['buy_type'] = 'item';
$offers[1]['buy_type_id'] = '2';
$offers[1]['name'] = 'item2';

$carts[2]['name'] = 'orange';
$carts[2]['brand_id'] = '3';
$carts[2]['item_id'] = '2';

$carts[4]['name'] = 'banana';
$carts[4]['brand_id'] = '6';
$carts[4]['item_id'] = '4';

$carts[6]['name'] = 'apple';
$carts[6]['brand_id'] = '1';
$carts[6]['item_id'] = '6';

foreach ($carts as $cart=>$c) {
    foreach ($offers as $offer=>$o) {

        if ($o['buy_type'] == 'brand' && $o['buy_type_id'] == $c['brand_id']) {
        // if this condition is true, add to $promo_brands array
            $promo_brands[$o['buy_type_id']][$cart] = $c;
        } else if ($o['buy_type'] == 'item' && $o['buy_type_id'] == $c['item_id']) {
        // otherwise if this condition is true, add to $promo_items array
            $promo_items[$cart] = $c;
        } else {
        // if none of the above, add to $regular_items
            $regular_items[$cart] = $c;
        }
    }
}
echo 'Promo Brands<br />';  
var_dump($promo_brands);
echo '<br />Promo Items<br />';
var_dump($promo_items);
echo '<br />Regular Items<br />';
var_dump($regular_items);
?>
```

Desired OUTPUT

```
Promo Brands
array(1) { [1]=> array(1) { [6]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(5) "apple" ["brand_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["item_id"]=> string(1) "6" } } } 
Promo Items
array(1) { [2]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(6) "orange" ["brand_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["item_id"]=> string(1) "2" } } 
Regular Items
array(1) { [4]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(6) "banana" ["brand_id"]=> string(1) "6" ["item_id"]=> string(1) "4" } }
```

**SOLVED:**

unsetting the array elements once it meets the condition before going to another condition(s)

```
$tmp_carts = $carts;
foreach ($tmp_carts as $cart=>$c) {
    foreach ($offers as $offer=>$o) {

        if ($o['buy_type'] == 'brand' && $o['buy_type_id'] == $c['brand_id']) {
        // if this condition is true, add to $promo_brands array
        $promo_brands[$o['buy_type_id']][$cart] = $c;
        unset($tmp_carts[$cart]);
        } else if ($o['buy_type'] == 'item' && $o['buy_type_id'] == $c['item_id']) {
        // otherwise if this condition is true, add to $promo_items array
        $promo_items[$cart] = $c;
        unset($tmp_carts[$cart]);
        } else {

        }
    }
}

$regular_items = $tmp_carts;
```

Comment: can you please paste also desired output you want ?

Comment: Your problem is in the data your receive which needs to be better organized.  Apparently none of your rules exclude apples and oranges.  It would be possible to hard code the exclusion but it probably wouldn't work with the front end for other things.  A redesign of the data provided is **mandatory**.

Comment: are you wanting to retrieve the banana always or do you need to retrieve it by name?

try the [in_array function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

foreach ($carts as $cart=>$c) {
 if(in_array("banana", $c)){
 echo "true";
}else{
 echo "nope";
 
}

Comment: Sorry if I haven't made myself clear. I will edit my question. I want to $regular_items array to include those that doesn't meet the prior conditions

Comment: @JuliePelletier I had expanded the $offers[$var]['buy_type_id'] to two, $offers[$var]['buy_brand_id'] and $offers[$var]['buy_item_id'] and didn't help. The if else sounds pretty straight forward. However, once it comes to foreach within foreach, it becomes complicated

Comment: I have attached answer same as you want.Please check. You can achieve it through `unset()` function. @MichaelEugeneYuen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just you need to check

Use `if` condition.

```
if($c['name'] == "banana")
{
    $regular_items[$cart] = $c;
}
```

**OR**

Use `in_array()`.

```
if(in_array("banana", $c))
{
    $regular_items[$cart] = $c;
}
```

**Code**

```
$offers[1]['buy_type'] = 'item';
$offers[1]['buy_type_id'] = '2';
$offers[1]['name'] = 'item2';

$carts[2]['name'] = 'orange';
$carts[2]['brand_id'] = '3';
$carts[2]['item_id'] = '2';

$carts[4]['name'] = 'banana';
$carts[4]['brand_id'] = '6';
$carts[4]['item_id'] = '4';

$carts[6]['name'] = 'apple';
$carts[6]['brand_id'] = '1';
$carts[6]['item_id'] = '6';

foreach ($carts as $cart=>$c) {
    foreach ($offers as $offer=>$o) {
        if ($o['buy_type'] == 'brand' && $o['buy_type_id'] == $c['brand_id']) {
            $promo_brands[$o['buy_type_id']][$cart] = $c;
        } else if ($o['buy_type'] == 'item' && $o['buy_type_id'] == $c['item_id']) {
            $promo_items[$cart] = $c;
        } else {
            if($c['name'] == "banana")
            {
                $regular_items[$cart] = $c;
            }
        }
    }
}
echo '<br />Regular Items<br />';   
print_r($regular_items);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Regular Items
Array
(
    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => banana
            [brand_id] => 6
            [item_id] => 4
        )

)
```

Use `unset()` to remove array elements which already comes in condition.

```
foreach ($carts as $cart=>$c) {
    foreach ($offers as $offer=>$o) {
        if ($o['buy_type'] == 'brand' && $o['buy_type_id'] == $c['brand_id']) {

            $promo_brands[$o['buy_type_id']][$cart] = $c;
            unset($carts[$cart]);
        } else if ($o['buy_type'] == 'item' && $o['buy_type_id'] == $c['item_id']) {
            $promo_items[$cart] = $c;
            unset($carts[$cart]);
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($carts);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => banana
            [brand_id] => 6
            [item_id] => 4
        )

)
```

Comment: Use this code it will give you same output as you have paste in your desire output. @MichaelEugeneYuen

Comment: I have added extra comments in my question

Comment: You need only banana array from your $cart array so i have added same code for you with desire output. Your Question is : `How can I get only banana in the $regular_items array (which doesn't fall into the first 2 conditions)? The following codes give me all 3 $cart array in the $regular_items array.`. Attached answer give you only **`banana`** array not all 3 carts. @MichaelEugeneYuen

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. I used banana only as a reference which doesn't fall into the first two conditions.  This name varies.

Comment: ok got it your question. let me try and let you know. @MichaelEugeneYuen

Comment: check my edited code. I have attached same as you want. below i have added unset() method which is same as you want dynamic. @MichaelEugeneYuen

Comment: thank you! straight and simple. Never thought of unsetting them.

Comment: Yes, Right... :) Welcome.. Glad to help you and sorry for late guessing your correct question. @MichaelEugeneYuen

Answer (score 0):

are you wanting to retrieve the banana always or do you need to retrieve it by name? try the in_array function

```
foreach ($carts as $cart=>$c) { 
if(in_array("banana", $c)){ 
    echo "true"; 
}else{ 
    echo "nope"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following trick, using `in_array` function.

```
$offers[0]['buy_type'] = 'brand';
$offers[0]['buy_type_id'] = '1';
$offers[0]['name'] = 'brand1';

$offers[1]['buy_type'] = 'item';
$offers[1]['buy_type_id'] = '2';
$offers[1]['name'] = 'item2';

$carts[2]['name'] = 'orange';
$carts[2]['brand_id'] = '3';
$carts[2]['item_id'] = '2';

$carts[4]['name'] = 'banana';
$carts[4]['brand_id'] = '6';
$carts[4]['item_id'] = '4';

$carts[6]['name'] = 'apple';
$carts[6]['brand_id'] = '1';
$carts[6]['item_id'] = '6';

$promo_brands = array();
$promo_items = array();
$regular_items = array();
$temp_regular_items = array();

foreach ($carts as $cart=>$c) {
    foreach ($offers as $offer=>$o) {
        if ($o['buy_type'] == 'brand' && $o['buy_type_id'] == $c['brand_id']) {
            $promo_brands[$cart] = $c;
        } else if ($o['buy_type'] == 'item' && $o['buy_type_id'] == $c['item_id']) {
            $promo_items[$cart] = $c;
        } else {
            $regular_items[$cart] = $c;
        }
    }
}

foreach($regular_items as $regitem => $r)
{
    if(!in_array($r, $promo_brands) && !in_array($r, $promo_items))
        $temp_regular_items[$regitem] = $r;
}


echo 'Promo Brands<br />';  
echo "<pre>"; print_r($promo_brands); echo "</pre>";
echo '<br />Promo Items<br />';
echo "<pre>"; print_r($promo_items); echo "</pre>";
echo '<br />Regular Items<br />';
echo "<pre>"; print_r($temp_regular_items); echo "</pre>";
```

This gives output as follows:

Promo Brands

```
Array
(
    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => apple
            [brand_id] => 1
            [item_id] => 6
        )

)
```

Promo Items

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => orange
            [brand_id] => 3
            [item_id] => 2
        )

)
```

Regular Items

```
Array
(
    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => banana
            [brand_id] => 6
            [item_id] => 4
        )

)
```

Hope this will help you..!

Comment: $promo_brands has to be two-dimentional as $cart['brand_id'] is not unique comparing with other $cart['brand_id']. Unless, I use another foreach or for loop to check this array